# hasPermission spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

what does this means ?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('DEVICE', {'DELETE','CREATE'})")
```

whether it checks Device object has DELETE AND CREATE both permission or any one of it?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your PermissionEvaluator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, it depends on which *PermissionEvaluator* you have. If you use the built-in ACL system, this will delegate to *DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy*. The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy.html) says:

> The method will iterate through each of the `permission`s in the order specified. For each iteration, all of the `sid`s will be considered, again in the order they are presented. A search will then be performed for the first `AccessControlEntry` object that directly matches that `permission:sid` combination. When the *first full match* is found, the grant or deny flag for that ACE will prevail. If the ACE specifies to grant access, the method will return `true`. If the ACE specifies to deny access, the loop will stop and the next `permission` iteration will be performed.

(sids = security identities, the user's principal and authorities)

In practice this means only **one of the permissions** is required for the method to return true.